# htaccess doens't call file config.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've trying set my htaccess and to call the file config.php but its not wotk, somewhere

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ config.php/$1 [QSA]


project
   - .htaccess
   - config.php
   path1
     - index
   path2
     - index
```

Comment: Is your web server apache? Are you sure that Apache is configured to use .htaccess files? You might want to [read up](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles) on how to make sure apache will even bother with an .htaccess file.

Comment: http://localhost/jaguartemas/

Comment: yep I use apache (xampp)

Comment: http://localhost/config.php/jaguartemas/ page not found

Comment: @anubhava yes its work if I call config its work

Comment: I put AcceptPathInfo On but nothing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, bacically I had forgotten the index file in root project

index.php

```
<?php  
  require 'config.php';
?>
```